# animationControllerForPresentedController not called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a custom animation to turn a controller like in the new wallet application.

I'm having a ViewController like this:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *testLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.transitioningDelegate = self;

    _testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _testLabel.text = @"View 1";

    [self.view addSubview:_testLabel];



    [_testLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.equalTo(self.view);
        make.height.equalTo(@50);
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.view);
        make.top.equalTo(self.mas_topLayoutGuide);
    }];

    _button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(push)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:_button];

    [_button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.center.equalTo(self.view);
        make.width.and.height.equalTo(@50);
    }];
}

- (void)push {
    NSLog(@"Push controller");
    BackViewController *vc = [[BackViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    TurnAnimationController *an = [[TurnAnimationController alloc] init];
    an.flipDirection = CEDirectionHorizontal;
    return an;
}
```

The method animationControllerForPresentedController is never called so my animation is never executed. I don't see the problem? I'm setting the transitioningDelegate to self?

Anyone an idea?

Comment: I need TurnAnimationController.h and TurnAnimationController.m file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of setting self as delegate like

> self.transitioningDelegate = self;

set transitioningDelegate of newly presented viewcontroller to self like your case

> BackViewController *vc = [[BackViewController alloc] init];
>   vc.transitioningDelegate = self;

Comment: Thank you :) :) :)

Answer (score 15):

Another requirement for `animationControllerForPresentedController` to be called is passing `true` as the `animated` parameter in `presentViewController:animated:completion`

If you call

`presentViewController(myVC, animated: false, completion: nil)`

then `animationControllerForPresentedController` won't be called even if you've set the `transitioningDelegate`.

Comment: passing true as the animated parameter helps me, thank you

Comment: Gah! Isn't it irritating when you after hours of troubleshooting and refactoring realize your code is working exactly as it should! You only had a bool set wrong... Thanks for pointing this mistake out though.